# How to find out version of Java component included in another Java package

Tags: jar, glassfish, version, grizzly

I'm trying to find out what version of Grizzly is included in each of the Oracle Glassfish server package, from 4.0 onwards. I tried googling for release notes, but couldn't find any other than 4.1.1 using Grizzly 2.3.23 (https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/glassfish-411-is-now-available), so I'm wondering if it's possible to inspect the JAR packages of the various Glassfish versions to figure out what versions of Grizzly it's using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The GlassFish source is on GitHub](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish) so you can just look at the source code. For Grizzly, the version is set in a property in the nucleus pom.xml here:

https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.0/nucleus/pom.xml#L133

To look at different versions, you can change the Tag using the dropdown at the top of the file. The line numbers are slightly different though, so here is a list for you:

- [GlassFish 4.0 has Grizzly 2.3.1](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.0/nucleus/pom.xml#L133)
- [GlassFish 4.1 has Grizzly 2.3.15-gfa](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.1/nucleus/pom.xml#L148)
- [GlassFish 4.1.1 has Grizzly 2.3.23](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.1.1/nucleus/pom.xml#L148)
- [GlassFish 4.1.2 has Grizzly 2.3.23](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.1.2/nucleus/pom.xml#L148)

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the glassfish server and you should eventually find grizzly somewhere, probably in a lib directory.

It seems like you can also just make a simple maven project (you will need maven installed) with a dependency on the glassfish kernel by creating a folder and placing a pom.xml file with the following in it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and then run `mvn dependency:tree` and you will end up with something like he following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/grizzly/nucleus-grizzly-all/4.1/nucleus-grizzly-all-4.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/grizzly/nucleus-grizzly-all/4.1/nucleus-grizzly-all-4.1.pom (8 KB at 6.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http/2.3.15-gfa/grizzly-http-2.3.15-gfa.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http/2.3.15-gfa/grizzly-http-2.3.15-gfa.pom (5 KB at 12.9 KB/sec)

...

[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.main.grizzly:nucleus-grizzly-all:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:2.3.15-gfa:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:2.3.15-gfa:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:2.3.15-gfa:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:jar:2.3.15-gfa:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.glassfish.main.grizzly:grizzly-config:jar:4.1:compile

...
```

You can then just change the version and run it again to see what version it uses, the available versions are here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.core/kernel

Comment: Hey thanks, I've never used maven nor glassfish before. How do I create a new maven project?

Comment: Looks like you got your answer above, there are plenty of resources on Maven on the web, just pick one and go!